# Are there any back compat guidelines for scala?

Tags: scala

For example, in Java its pretty well known that adding a method to an interface is backwards compatible as long as signatures are not removed.  Same with adding fields/methods to objects, as long as constructors are not modified.

I'm having a hard time knowing what are some guidelines in scala? Is adding a self type back compat? Is adding a new optional field on a case class with a default value back compat? I'm using MIMA to verify binary compatibility, but it only verifies TRUE binary compatibility, and not necessarily backwards compatibility such that if someone uses V1.1 of a library but uses code linked against V1 that the linked code will still play nice.

Comment: sbt has a rich plugin ecosystem, so they have a lot of experience with binary compatibility.  http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Coding-Guideline.html  notably they've been stuck on Scala 2.10 for years now.